# How do I type carriage return?

Tags: windows, linux

How do I type a carriage return control character, in Windows or in Linux?

I'd like to type a backspace character too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Linux, your keyboard will send carriage return if you type <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>, linefeed when you type <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>, and backspace when you type <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd>.  Can't say with Windows, since you can be typing into so many different kinds of text-input controls, including a console window.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type `013` on the numpad.

Comment: Note that this is Windows-only

Answer (score 8):

In linux, backspace is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, carriage return is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

If you want to insert a *literal* carriage return/backspace, you must quote it. Quoting is program-specific, but usually (or at least in `bash`) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> quotes the next character. Other programs have different quoting mechanism, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in `emacs` or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in `nano`

Therefore:

- To insert a carriage return in `bash`, you would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- To insert a backspace in `nano` you would press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- To insert a carriage return in `emacs`, you would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Edit: To insert another control character, look in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29) table in the first column. For example, to type an escape character you would press `^[` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>)

Comment: It seems to be `Alt+V` in nano?

Comment: Whoops! I'll fix the answer

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value for the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) carriage return character is 13. With Microsoft Windows, hold down the <ALT> key and type the numbers "13" on the numeric keypad; the row of numeric above QWERTY won't work. This will insert the "♪" character in to your document.

You can also copy the "♪" character from this answer and paste it in to your document as well.