# How can I input ASCII control characters in general into Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Related Question: [how to type carriage return](https://superuser.com/questions/433903/how-to-type-carriage-return)

Characters like the carriage return, denoted by '^M', along with others such as '^A' '^B' etc.

Currently, I'm only able to accomplish this by using another editor to input it and then reload it in Sublime.

The intent is not to repair line endings, which I'm aware can be done by "View > Line Endings", nor is it to remove these characters. I'm trying to input it using Sublime Text 3, without using external tools, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the hex code of your special character, you can use the **find/replace** functionality.

1. Select some area where you want to place your special character,
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (to activate **find/replace**)
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (to select Regular expression)
4. Type any ANSI character you need in encoded form, say, `\x1b`,
5. Press replace.

You will see this special character printed as `<0x1b>`.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value for the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) carriage return character is 13. If you're using Sublime with Microsoft Windows, hold down the <ALT> key and type the numbers "13" on the numeric keypad; the row of numeric keys won't work. This will insert the "♪" character in to your document.

You can also copy the "♪" character from this answer and paste it in to your document as well.